# Macro Excel: Exportar hojas especificas en excel

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Tengo un documento de excel con 7 Hojas

Reporte Enero | Reporte Febrero | Activos Enero | Activos Febrero | Datos

Quiero exportar en pdf unicamente las hojas que incluyan el nombre de reporte.

```
Dim Ruta As String
Dim NombreArchivo As String
Dim Hoja As Object


With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = " Respaldo"
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
     ' NADA
    Else
        Ruta = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If


    For Each Hoja In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If Hoja.Name Like "*REPORTE*" Then

    ''' Como integrar las hojas en un workbook para exportarlas

        End If
    Next


End With
```

Answer (score 1):

El objeto `Worksheet` tiene un método llamado `ExportAsFixedFormat`, precisamente se usa para exportar la hoja a pdf.

realice unos pequeños cambios adicionales, es el caso de la variable Hoja, la he cambiado del tipo `Object` a `Worksheet`, de ese modo al poner el punto después de "`Hoja`" aparecerán sus propiedades y métodos en lista desplegable.
También modifique la condición del `If` para la selección del ítem (ubicación de respaldo ) en el cuadro de dialogo, no es necesario hacer una condición que al cumplirse no hace nada, por eso también se elimina el `Else`, la condición se cumple solo si se ha seleccionado una ubicación, si no se selecciona nada, en el propio cuadro de dialogo sale un error, por eso no hace falta el `Else`.

```
Sub ReslapdoHojasPDF()
    Dim Ruta As String
    Dim NombreArchivo As String
    Dim Hoja As Worksheet

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = " Respaldo"
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            Ruta = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If

        For Each Hoja In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
            NombreArchivo = Hoja.Name
            If Hoja.Name Like "*Reporte*" Then
                Hoja.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=Ruta & "\" & NombreArchivo, _
                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias, no me di a entender en la pregunta bien, como puedo exportar las 2 hojas de reporte en un solo documento, ya que en el ejemplo, convierte cada hoja en un archivo separado.

Answer (score 0):

El siguiente código creará una matriz con todas las hojas cuyo nombre contenga la palabra `Reporte`, y las exportará a PDF. No olvides personalizar la ruta donde guardarlas.

```
Dim wk As Worksheet
Dim MiMatriz As Variant
Dim str As String

For Each wk In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If InStr(1, wk.Name, "reporte ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then str = str & wk.Name & "|" 'ponemos vbTextCompare para no distinguir entre mayúsculas o minúsculas
Next wk

str = Left(str, Len(str) - 1) 'para quitar el último |
MiMatriz = Split(str, "|") 'lo pasamos a matriz

    Sheets(MiMatriz).Select 'seleccionamos matriz de hojas
    Sheets(MiMatriz(0)).Activate 'activamos la primera de la matriz
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "D:\Temp\Libro1.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:= _
        True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False 'exportamos a PDF

        ''IMPORTANTE!!! LUEGO SELECCIONA UNA HOJA QUE NO ESTÉ EN LA MATRIZ, O SE TE QUEDARÁN PERMANENTEMENTE SELECCIONADAS
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Hoja1").Select
```